# Css image positioning issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place my logo on the page, and move it down and to the left to overlap with part of the sections.. The top has no issues, it overlaps to the content area as desired, but i want to move it to left, but when i do that, part of the text is being cut off.. (Bowling should be the logo, but as you see, half of the B is gone.. ) Not sure what is causing this, and need help to fix it.

- The page background is white
- The Wrapper is Black
- I want part of the logo to be on white to left of the black wrapper area (as shown in the image)

Currently
[image: Currently]

Desired Look
[image: Desired Look!]

css file:

```
body{
    margin:0px 0px; padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
}
h1{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#Wrapper{
    width:900px;
    margin:0px auto;
    min-height:100%;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#Header{
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 150px;
}

#ContentWrapper{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
}

#Content{
    margin-left: 200px;
    text-align: left;
}

/* HEADER */
#Logo{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    left: -35px;

}

.imgLogo{

}
#HeaderLogin{
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: -30px;
}

#HeaderLoginEmail{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#HeaderLoginPassword{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#HeaderLoginButton{
    float:left;
}
```

html file:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="base2.css">
    <body>
<div id="Wrapper">
  <div id="Header">
    <div id="Logo">
        <img class="imgLogo" src="images/logo2.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="HeaderLogin">
      <div id="HeaderLoginEmail">
           <input class="txtHeaderLogin" placeholder="Email" /> <br />
                <label class="lblHeaderLogin">Forgot Email?</label>
      </div>

      <div id="HeaderLoginPassword">
        <input class="txtHeaderLogin" placeholder="Password" /> <br />
        <label class="lblHeaderLogin">Forgot Password?</label>
      </div>

      <div id="HeaderLoginButton">
        <a href="#" class="btnHeaderLogin">LOGIN</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ContentWrapper">
    <div id="Content">

    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The logo appears to be moved left (-35px) off the edge of the page. Is there content to the left you're trying to overlap? I'm confused because you specifically said you're trying to move the logo left to overlap something, but there doesn't seem to be any content to the left.

Comment: I have added the desired look... The whole page is white background.. The center section is black (wrapper).. I want the logo to be as desired.

Comment: The code you've supplied doesn't match your first "Currently" image, is any code missing? This is what your given code looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/cUAp5/

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yc6Qa/1/

Instead of floating the Logo left and setting a negative margin, I set the logo to `position: absolute;` and used `left: 0;`. The rest of your CSS/HTML is untouched.
Depending in the rest of your site, this solution will suit you well.

Answer (score 0):

change your logo css :

```
#Logo{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    left: 0px;

}
```

Basically remove the negative left.